# Type mismatch error when using the range.find

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

As part of a larger code, I am looking for a value in a spreadsheet (1.xlsx) in another spreadsheet (all defaults.xls). I am running the macro from a word document and that is why I am importing both spreadsheets as objects. However, doing so using the *range.find* function always returns a type mismatch error. The code is below

```
Dim OXL As Object
Set OXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set OWB = OXL.Workbooks.Open("All Defaults.xls")
Set OWB2 = OXL.Workbooks.Open("1.xlsx")

OWB.ActiveSheet.Range("E:E").Find(What:=OWB2.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

I have tried, instead of just activating the function, assigning the value of the find function to an object or a variant but I still get the same mismatch error.
Running the same *find* function within an excel macro gives no errors.
Edit: I have also tried writing the actual value in the code instead of *OWB2.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")* but the same error occurs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things going on here:

- `ActiveSheet` is a property of `Excel.Application`, not `Workbook`.  So use `OXL.ActiveSheet`
- Word doesn't know `ActiveCell`, so use `OXL.ActiveCell`
- Even then, `After` must be a cell in the search range
- Word dosn't know the named constants for `Find`. So use there values.

So, change to

```
OXL.ActiveSheet.Range("E:E").Find(What:=OXL.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value, After:=OXL.Range("E1"), LookIn:=-4123, LookAt:=2, SearchOrder:=1, SearchDirection:=1, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

After all that, consider

- You should declare *all* your variables
- You should specify the full path to the workbook, rather than relying of default locations
- How do you know which sheet will be active whan you open the book? Specify the one you want
- How do you know the `Find` will find a result?  Allow for the possibility it fails
- You should get a reference to the found cell, rather than `Activate`ing it
- Consider Early Bound code, rather then Late Bound.  There are good reasons to use either.
- `GetObject(, "Excel.Application")` assumes an instance of Excel is running.  What if ther's not? Your code should handle that case

Somethin like

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim oXL As Object ' Excel.Application
    Dim oWB As Object ' Excel.Workbook
    Dim oWB2 as Object ' Excel.Workbook
    Dim oSH As Object ' Excel.Worksheet
    Dim oSearchRange As Object ' Excel.Range
    Dim oRng As Object ' Excel.Range

    Set oXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Full\Path\To\All Defaults.xls")
    Set oWB2 = oXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\Full\Path\To\1.xlsx")
    Set oSH = oWB.Worksheets("SpecifySheet")
    Set oSearchRange = oSH.Range("E:E")
    Set oRng = oSearchRange.Find( _
      What:=oSH.Range("A1").Value, _
      After:=oSearchRange.Cells(1, 1), _
      LookIn:=-4123, _
      LookAt:=2, _
      SearchOrder:=1, _
      SearchDirection:=1, _
      MatchCase:=False, _
      SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not oRng Is Nothing Then
        oRng.Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Using the command you stated at first no longer gives an error, but for some reason the search gives back nothing even though I know the value exists. I even tried having two different excel applications, one for each workbook (source and target) but still nothing. Trying your code at the second part still gives the type mismatch error. I believe you are missing the fact that I am navigating two different workbooks, looking in one for a value that is present in the other.

Comment: @kereemostafa I've shown you the reasons your code failed, and some techniques to address those issues.  The exact requirements of your task are not clear in your post, but given the info I've provided I'm sure you can take it from here

Comment: @kereemostafa your edit states you tried `OWB2.ActiveSheet.Range("A1")` : you clearly havn't understood my answer. So again, `ActiveSheet` is a property of the Application object `oXL`, not a workbook `oWB2`.  And again, don't use ActiveSheet, set and use a reference to the sheet you actually want.